# Making input box not overflow window width

Tags: html, css, input, width, project

I am working on a project: **web terminal**.
 In it, the format is something this

`<div class="prompt">C:/users/somebody/ </div> <input type="text" class="usrcommand">`

Here, the width of `.prompt` is not definite(changes according to user) and the input tag should cover the remaining portion that is left after `.prompt`.

Note that: `.prompt` has been styled: **display: inline**

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try **display:inline-block** rule on both the classes (.prompt and usrcommand)